# Hunting for an (old?) 68HC11 Cross-Assembler

Tags: 68hc11

A friend has asked for help with some 68HC11 assembly code. The code was written for a DOS/Windows cross-assembler with an executable name of X68C11. Does anyone know if that assembler can still be found, or if there is a compatible assembler that exists?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found that the assembler does still exist. The original creator, 2500 AD software, was bought by [Avocet](http://www.avocetsystems.com), who has kept up the [68HC11 product line](http://www.avocetsystems.com/company/techshee/asheets/68HC11.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [link](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/microcontroller-faq/68hc11/) that might point you in the direction to find the sources...I did see that there is a way to use the GNU's gcc toolchain to produce a cross-compiled binary...

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Man, that's some old stuff. Bunch of dead links, etc. so far, but I remain hopeful. The real problem is there's a pretty good chunk of source, and I sure as heck don't want to port it all if it's not completely necessary.

Comment: @Harper: check this out, maybe with cygwin and this...http://www.gnu.org/software/m68hc11/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about X68C11, but my University of Michigan - Dearborn curriculum required me to program a 68HC11 using a cross-assembler called AsmIDE, which you can download at http://support.technologicalarts.ca/docs/HC12-related/ThirdParty/AsmIDE/ .  That seems to be the only link to it I can find on the Internet, since the developer died and his websites were all shut down.  If you want to use C, the same guy wrote a handy GCC IDE called EmbeddedGNU available at http://www.evbplus.com/hcs12_9s12/EmbeddedGNU_hcs12.html .

Comment: Disregard the "HC12-related" in the URL above -- AsmIDE is compatible with both the HC11 and HC12 instruction sets.